# How to restrict a <apex:inputField> for decimal value upto 5?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, salesforcedx, dynamic-visualforce

```
<apex:inputField value="{!expence}" styleClass="slds-input inputWidth August" 
                                            onchange="updateAfterBlur();" />
```

Input - 12.22222 (Decimal value should not increase the length 5 such as .22222)
User should not be able to enter more then 5 digits after decimal and as many number user wants before decimal.
Only the condition is for after decimal.

To be done by javascript.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried with key codes and i can work with that but my client doesnt want the key codes to be used so i need a different solution and it is mandate to use apex:inputField

Comment: You can use number field and put decimal place 5 and you can create validation rule if after decimal limit is more than 5 then show the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce recommends lesser javascript on visualforce though...
Whether you want to convert the number in two decimal places you may use the function toFixed(value) [Method Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp). However, you want to restrict the values when users type. Please try using the following code

```
var check = function(x) {
  var y = x.value;
  x.value = (y.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? (y.substr(0, y.indexOf(".")) + 
  y.substr(y.indexOf("."), 6)) : y;
}
```

the number 6 defines how many values after the decimal

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following format

```
<apex:outputtext value="{0,Number,0.00000}" >
   <apex:param value="{!expence}"/>
 </apex:outputtext>
```

Comment: The question is about `<apex:inputField>` rather than `<apex:outputField>` or `outputText`; this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: No error should be shown is the criteria well i got the solution thanks....@israel